# how to copy a layer in photoshop to export image for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I'm trying to export some images of a photoshop design and this is how I usually do it:

1. select the layer you want.
2. command + left click the thumbnail to create a marquee around the layer
3. copy it (command + c)
4. Create a new file (command + n). this will create a file with the exact dimensions as the layer
5. paste in the copied layer. (command + v)
6. save for web

For certain layers I get stuck on number 4 where photoshop doesn't know that I copied something onto the clipboard so the right dimensions aren't displayed. plus pasting doesn't work because for some reason it was never copied. I don't know if certain layers cannot be copied simply by pressing command + c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking your layer in the layer palette and selecting `Duplicate Layer`. In the resulting pop up, set the Document option to `New`. This will take care of steps 2-6 in your workflow.

You could also add that (and the save for web) to an action or script for 1-click functionality.

Comment: This is what I do, except I add `Image > Trim > Transparent areas` after duplicating, then save for web.

Comment: Thank you John and Scott. This helps a lot thank you both! I'm wondering why certain layers cannot be copied to the clipboard by doing command + c....

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:
Edit --> Copy Merged.
You'll copy all layers do you want (selected) and you can export it.

Comment: This doesn't really help me as there are other layers inside it that would be merged along with the one I specifically want. For example, if I just want to copy a background gradient color of a banner but not the images and text inside the banner. doing copy merged would copy the background along with everything in it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd>!

Steps [Follow one time only, you will be able to export any layer with a single click!] :

- Select the layer or group containing your asset.
- Open your actions palette (window > actions).
- Hit the "Create New Action Button", and name it. (example, "Asset to File").
- Press record .
- Right click on the layer or group title and click "Duplicate.
  Layer/Group".
- In the dialog that pops up, change the destination document to "New"
  and hit OK.
- Now you have a new Photoshop document with just that isolated asset!
- In the menu bar, select Image > Trim... > Transparent Pixels.
- Now your document is exactly the size of your asset, to the exact
  pixel.
- Save for Web (works cleanly since you're saving the whole document -
  no accidental extras or generated file names).
- Close your document.
- Hit the stop button .
- Select your action in the actions palette.
- Open the actions palette context menu  and select "Action
  Options".
- Choose a function key (I selected <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) (and an optional modifier key if needed).